# How to verify received token from firebase for device in php/laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a mobile application which I'm getting device token from firebase, to send notification to device by user's device token.

I'm not using firebase/google authentication or etc.

I'm just using cloud messaging to send notification, which I need device token, to send notifications to specific users and right now, I need to validate the token before application store token in DB.

How to verify received device token from firebase to make sure the token is exist/real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way was to send a basic and empty message using the token.

```
$response = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'key=token'])
   ->post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', [
            'registration_ids' => [ tokens here ],
        ]);
```

If you enter wrong token, you'll get response like below :

```
{
    "multicast_id": xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InvalidRegistration"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which in case of success response your result will be :

```
{
    "multicast_id": xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "x:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

So in general, need to decode json response and just check the result.